# How to delete "space" between author1 and comma in citation

Tags: spacing, citing, natbib

I created my bibliography style (author-year) in "custom-bib" using `natbib`. Then I replace `and` with `,` (between author1 and author2) using `\providecommand{\BIBand}{,}`. As a result, I received the following citation in the text

> (Author1[space1],[space2]author2,[space3]year).

I have a question: How delete from citation in the text [space1]?

Comment: Try with `\renewcommand{\BIBand}{\unskip, \ignorespaces}`. Either way, it would be great if we could experiment using your actual `.bst` with an example that replicates the current behaviour. Can you provide that with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: Bibliography style files created with the `makebst` utility -- part of the [custom-bib](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib) package -- feature functions named `bbl.and` and `space.word`, to be used with bib entries that have exactly two authors. If you're not using these functions or if you have modified them via macros named, say, `\BIBand`, you should tell us about these measures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using

```
\renewcommand{\BIBand}{\unskip, \ignorespaces}
```

This should remove any preceding and following spaces around `,`.

Comment: Werner, one more time thank you very much for your answer. It works!